# Chain rule mismatch

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

> Let
> $$
> g\bigl(h(t)\bigr) = \cos(\sqrt{t})
> $$ and
> $$
> g(t) = \cos(t) 
> $$
> and
> $$
> h(t) = \sqrt{t}.
> $$
> Verify that
> $$
> \frac{dg}{dh} = \frac{\;\frac{dg}{dt}\;}{\frac{dh}{dt}}.
> $$

I tried doing this but I got
$$
\frac{dg}{dh} = -\sin(\sqrt{t}) \cdot \frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}
$$
but that is not equal to
$$
\frac{\frac{dg}{dt}}{\frac{dh}{dt}} = -2\sin(t) \cdot \sqrt{t}
$$

Where did I make a mistake?
Edit: I see the mistake but I tried another method and I don't know why that is wrong.
$$\frac{dg}{dh}=-sin\left(h\right)\cdot \frac{dh}{dh}=-sin\left(\sqrt{t}\right)$$

Comment: Why are all of the answers, which are all correct, downvoted?

Comment: @Chris I am not the downvoter, but I imagine it is because they don't answer the question, "Where did I make a mistake?", but they simply provide their own (different) solution to the problem. So they may contain correct statements, but they are not valid answers.

Comment: I did not downvote any of them either but I think that only @user170231 answered my question. I still don't know why my method doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first derivative you found is $\dfrac{dg(h(t))}{dt}$, whereas you must compute $\dfrac{dg}{dh}$.

Since $h(t)=\sqrt t$, you have $g(t) = \cos(h(t)^2)$, and so

$$\frac{dg}{dh} = -\sin(h(t)^2) \cdot 2 h(t) = -2\sqrt t\,\sin(t)$$

On the other hand, by the chain rule,

$$\frac{dg}{dh} = \frac{\frac{dg}{dt}}{\frac{dh}{dt}} = \frac{-\sin(t)}{\frac1{2\sqrt t}} = -2\sqrt t\,\sin(t)$$

Comment: Why don’t you need to multiple by the derivative of t with respect to h in the fourth line?

Comment: The chain rule says $\dfrac{\frac{dg}{dt}}{\frac{dh}{dt}}=\dfrac{dg}{dt}\cdot\dfrac{dt}{dh}$. In the latter form, you would have to determine the inverse function of $h$, which isn't hard but requires one more step. $h(t)=\sqrt t\implies t=h(t)^2$, hence$$\frac{dt}{dh}=2h\implies\frac{dg}{dh}=-\sin(t)\cdot 2h(t)$$and we get the same result.

Comment: I have a couple of questions because I am feeling confused

1) $\frac{dg}{dh}$ is the same as $\frac{dg\left(h\left(t\right)\right)}{dh}$ right?


2) Why can't we do the following: $\frac{dg}{dh}=-sin\left(\sqrt{t}\right)\cdot \frac{d\sqrt{t}}{dh}$?

Comment: After thinking for a bit I think that 1 is correct but I still don't know why what I did in part two doesn't work.

Comment: (1) Yes, because $h$ is a function of $t$. Here's another example that may help explain why: suppose $g(t)=t^2$ and $h(t)=t^3$. Then $g(h)=h^2$, while $g(h(t))=\left(t^3\right)^2=t^6$. Using only the power rule, we have derivatives$$\frac{dg(h)}{dh}=2h,\frac{dg(h(t))}{dt}=6t^5,\frac{dh(t)}{dt}=3t^2$$With the chain rule, we get$$\frac{dg(h(t))}{dh}=\frac{dg(h(t))}{dt}\cdot\frac{dt}{dh}=\frac{\frac{dg(h(t))}{dt}}{\frac{dh}{dt}}=\frac{6t^5}{3t^2}=2t^3=2h(t)$$which agrees with $\dfrac{dg}{dh}$ after you replace $h$ with $h(t)=t^3$ in that result.

Comment: (2) In this exercise, $g(h)=\cos(h)$, so $\dfrac{dg}{dh}=-\sin(h)$ and you would stop there. You could go on to replace $h$ with $\sqrt t$, but then this is the derivative $g$ with respect to $\sqrt t$, not $t$, so you need the chain rule again.$$\frac{dg}{dh}=-\sin(h)\implies\frac{dg}{d\sqrt t}=\frac{dg}{dt}\cdot\frac{dt}{d\sqrt t}=\frac{\frac{dg}{dt}}{\frac{d\sqrt t}{dt}}=\frac{-\sin(t)}{\frac1{2\sqrt t}}=-2\sqrt t\,\sin\left(\left(\sqrt t\right)^2\right)$$

Comment: But doesn't that contradict the value that I got when I did  $$\frac{\frac{dg}{dt}}{\frac{dh}{dt}}=\frac{dg}{dh}=2sin\left(t\right)\cdot \sqrt{t}$$ which is not equal to $$\frac{dg}{dh}=-sin\left(h\right)$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144628/discussion-between-user170231-and-effie-johnson).

Answer (score 3):

To solve your problem here, you need to write $g$ in terms of $h$, i.e. if
$$g(t)=\cos(t)$$
and:
$$h(t)=\sqrt{t}$$
then:
$$g(h)=\cos(h^2)$$
Then:
$$\frac{dg}{dh}=-2\sin(h^2)h=-2\sin(t)\sqrt{2}$$
We see that:
$$\frac{dg}{dt}=-\sin(t)$$
and:
$$\frac{dh}{dt}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}$$
Hence:
$$\frac{\frac{dg}{dt}}{\frac{dh}{dt}}=-2\sin(t)\sqrt{t}$$
as desired.

Edit:

So the main issue here is that you are mildly conflating notation, which is understandable in this case. If we first write that:

$$g(h)=\cos(h)$$

then it is absolutely true that:

$$\frac{dg}{dh}=-\sin(h)$$

Furthermore, if we have two function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (these are not the proper domains/ranges of the two specific functions, but you can easily modify this), then we can compose the two functions to obtain a new function $g\circ h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. The chain rule then states that the derivative is given by:

$$\frac{d(g\circ h)}{dt}=\frac{dg}{dh}\frac{dh}{dt}$$

However, this is not what you are asking in your post. What you are starting with is two functions $g(t)=\cos(t)$ and $h(t)=\sqrt(t)$. If we fix these two functions, then we can not simply write:
$$\frac{dg}{dh}=-\sin(h)$$
because $g$ is a function of $t$ not $h$. We can think of $dg/dh$ in this case as asking how does $g(t)$ change as $h(t)$ changes. To do this, we need to be able to take the derivative of $g(t)$ with respect to $h$, i.e. we need to rewrite the $t$ coordinate in terms of $h$. Once you do that, it all works out.

This is I think mildly easier to comprehend in the context of parametric curves. Suppose we have a map $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ where:
$$f(t)=(h(t),g(t))$$
Here, we can think of the $h$ as the $x$ coordinate, and $g$ as the $y$ coordinate of the curve. If you graph this out you'll see you get the graph of a function, so what $dg/dh$ is finding, is more like the usual derivative $dy/dx$. But to calculate such a derivative, we need to write $y$ in terms of $x$, or else how are we going to differentiate some function of $t$ with respect to $x$?

Does that clear things up?

Comment: I understand why your method works and why the one I used in the post doesn't work but now I don't know why this method doesn't work.
$$\frac{dg}{dh}=-sin\left(h\right)\cdot \frac{dh}{dh}=-sin\left(\sqrt{t}\right)$$
I also wanted to ask if $$\frac{dg}{dh}=\frac{dg\left(h\left(t\right)\right)}{dh}$$

Comment: What about the function g(h(t)) = -sin(sqrt(t)) the composition of the the functions you listed above. Doesn’t that make g a function of h?

Comment: @EffieJohnson Yes, but not in the same sense as taking $g(t)=\cos(t)$ and differentiating that function with respect to $h$.

Answer (score 1):

Your functions are $g(t) = \cos(t)$ and $h(t) = \sqrt{t}$. Now you wish to find the derivative of $g$ with respect to $h$. So we can figure it out like this:
$$
\begin{align} \frac{dg}{dh} &= \frac{d}{d(\sqrt{t})}(\cos(t))\\
&=\frac{d}{d(\sqrt{t})}[\cos((\sqrt{t})^2)]\\
\text{Let} \ \sqrt{t} = u\text{,} & \\[4pt]
\therefore \frac{dg}{dh} &=\frac{d}{d(u)}[\cos(u^2)]\\
&= -2u\cdot \sin(u^2) 
\end{align}
$$
Replacing $u = \sqrt{t}$, we get $$\frac{dg}{dh} = -2\sqrt{t} \cdot \sin(t)$$

Now, I believe you were able to find the RHS so I am not showing it here. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{dg}{dh}=\frac{d}{dh}g(t)$ where $h=\sqrt{t}$, $h^2=t$

so $\frac{dg}{dh}=\frac{d}{dh}g(h^2)=\frac{d}{dh}\cos(h^2)=-\sin(h^2)\cdot 2h=-\sin(t)\cdot 2\sqrt{t}$