Confusion using function composition
I've tried asking this question on here before but I've recently realized that I was asking the wrong question.

Let $g(t)=cos(t)$, and $h(t)=\sqrt{t}$. Is $g(h(t)) = cos(\sqrt{t}) = cos(h)$ the same as $g(h)$? Can you even get to the last step of $cos(h)$ or does it have to be $cos(h(t))$?
This aligns with the logic that to find $g(h)$, you can simply plug in $h$ into $g(t)=cos(t)$ and get $(h)=cos(h)$.
However, according to https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4659187/1079032, $g(h)=h^2$.

Notationally, $g(h(t)) = \cos(h)$ doesn’t make much sense. The left-hand side represents the function $g \circ h$ acting on $t$, while the right-hand side doesn’t act on $t$. But what you have there is somewhat correct: we have that $g(h(t)) = \cos(h(t))$ implies $g(h)= \cos(h)$. Just note for all this to make sense, your domains and codomains need to act nice with each other.

What about the answer that I got before that said that $g(h) = h^2$? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4659187/1079032

I assume that the confusion is arising in the following line from the linked answer:

Since $h(t)=\sqrt t$, you have $g(t)=\cos(h(t)^2)$, [...]

You are trying to find $g$ as a function of $h$, where both $g$ and $h$ are given as functions of $t$. This is not equivalent to composing $g$ and $h$ as you have done. Put another way, you are not trying to find $g(h(t))$; you are trying to find $g(t)$* in a form which relies on $h(t)$, but not $t$ directly.
From the definition of $h$, it should be clear that $t=h(t)^2$. Substituting this into the expression for $g$, we get $g(t)=\cos(h(t)^2)$, as the previous answer found. From here, it is a fairly simple matter to derive $\frac{dg}{dh}$.

*The function which results from finding $g(t)$ in terms of $h(t)$ may be called $g(h)$ for brevity, but this is an abuse of notation, defining two different functions to $g$. I don't recommend doing this, at least without more experience with this sort of problem.

Edit: Hyperlink scrolled me to the wrong answer. I see where one answer says $g(h)=\cos(h^2)$. The meaning and source of this equation are identical to the $g(t)=\cos(h(t)^2)$ that the accepted answer uses (see note* above). I believe the latter is much more understandable and rigorous in its notation.
